# Does GCP support P2S?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, point-to-site-vpn

According to [this documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-connect-google-cloud-platform-networks-via-vpn-622e47d510ba#.7gp0ydtfu) Google Cloud Platform supports Site-to-site (S2S) VPN, but does it support point-to-site (P2S) as well?

Comment: No at this moment it doesn't support road warrior scenario's https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-to-gateway(road warrior) setup is not supported by [CloudVPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview) as Lennert mentioned in his comment. For client-to-gateway scenarios, you can install and configure an IPSec VPN software, like Strongswan on a GCE VM and configure it for remote access. Users can than connect to this VPN server through VPN client and, after a secure tunnel established they can connect to all other VMs which are deployed inside the same network. With this setup, you can also configure NAT gateway and remove the public IP from other VMs. Configuring a NAT gateway is described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway). The other option for road warrior scenarios can be using VPN over SSH.